# Electron Cannot Execute Javascript To Check If Div Exists

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to check whether a div with classname exists in the current page view. I tried to use javascript to find the element and send the result using IPC but I get a 'Script failed to execute error` and I am unsure how to resolve this.

Below is my code which opens a page, checks if a div is present by executing javascript, sends the result from the renderer back to main and applies the proper css according to what was sent back. (With my limited knowledge of front end I feel like this is the incorrect approach though).

**index.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

const DOMAIN_URL = "instagram.com"

let win;

function createWindow () {

  const options = {
    width: 500,
    height: 550,
    resizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    movable: true,
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    title: 'InstaSend',
    webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false
        },
  };

  // create main window
  win = new BrowserWindow(options)
  win.loadURL('https://'+DOMAIN_URL)

  // check if we are at the login page
  win.webContents.on('dom-ready', function (e) {
    win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
      var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
      var hasLogin = document.getElementsbyClassName("gr27e")[0];
      ipcRenderer.send('checkLogin', hasLogin)
    `);
    });

  ipcMain.on('checkLogin', function(event, hasLogin){
    console.log(hasLogin);
    if(!hasLogin){
      win.resizable = true
      win.maximizable = true
      win.setSize(1100,950, true)
      win.webContents.insertCSS(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/dash.css'), 'utf8'));
    }else{
      win.webContents.insertCSS(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/ig.css'), 'utf8'));
    }

  })
}

app.on('ready', function(){
  createWindow()
});
```

**error output:**

```
internal/process/warning.js:27 (node:89911) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Script failed to execute, this normally means an error was thrown. Check the renderer console for the error.
    at WebFrame../lib/renderer/api/web-frame.ts.WebFrame.<computed> [as executeJavaScript] (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:1590:33)
    at electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:2844:43
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:2419:57)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Object.onMessage (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:2188:16)
writeOut @ internal/process/warning.js:27
2internal/process/warning.js:27 (node:89911) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
writeOut @ internal/process/warning.js:27
2internal/process/warning.js:27 (node:89911) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set  `nodeIntegration` to true. Otherwise you cannot use `require`.

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        },
```

Furthermore, you have a typo, please check the capital letters to write `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Unfortunately, I see same error in chrome's remote inspect

Comment: You have written `getElementsbyClassName`instead of `getElementsByClassName` with a capital `B`. Does it work now ?

Comment: This works now, thank you! First time doing front web.. Im editing with Atom. Is there any way to check code syntax that is embedded in a string or is it something we must deal with?

Comment: Yes, you have to open the Dev Tools of you Electron app (as if you were in Chrome) (Ctrl+Maj+i ou Cmd+Alt+i)